# Adding a new node in JSTree

Tags: jquery

I am working on below JSTree plugin.

http://www.jstree.com/

What I am interested in is when i click on node

1. Make a call to server
2. Add new node

I found `on change` event and it triggers when I click the node but dont know how i can add a new node.

```
<div id="SPListCollection">
  <ul>
    <li>Root node 1</li>
    <li>Root node 2</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script>
$('#SPListCollection').jstree();
$('#jstree').on("changed.jstree", function (e, data) {
        console.log(data.selected);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Did you try this ?


 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821006/creating-a-new-node-in-jstree?rq=1
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821006/creating-a-new-node-in-jstree

Comment: @Keerthi yes that worked

Comment: @Keerthi is there a way where i can show spinning wheel while server is returning response?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `create_node` for adding new nodes dynamically.

[http://www.jstree.com/api/#/?f=create_node([obj, node, pos, callback, is_loaded])](http://www.jstree.com/api/#/?f=create_node([obj,%20node,%20pos,%20callback,%20is_loaded]))

Comment: Is there a way where i can show spinning wheel while server is returning response?

Comment: Yes you can put the image inside a div and show it before service call and hide it after adding node. You can centre the div using Css

Answer (score 1):

You can add the spinner by

```
$(function () {

$("div.spinner").show();

$('#jstree').bind("loaded.jstree", function (e, data) {
    // tree has been loaded
    $("div.spinner").hide();
});

});
```

Comment: Sorry if you think its silly but where is "spinner" class defined? or do i have to define?

Comment: You have to define it. Like <div class="spinner" style="display:none"><img src="/path" /></div>. Position the DIV according to your requirement.